# Battery for ESP32 + Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor 1.2

Tags: batteries, sensor, esp32

I have got a very beginner question.
I am planning to use the ESP32 microcontroller wired up with some sensors, such as this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N11R8MD)
The sensor has an Operating Voltage: DC 3.3-5.5V, so I was planning to use a battery for running the ESP32, possibly at 3.3 V. Said that, do you think the sensor is going to have a huge impact in the battery life or it is the micro itself that is going to draw the most current?
Please note that my process will be to get the sensor value, send it through wifi and then going in deep sleep mode for half a day or so.
Has anyone experience in using this device with battery (and sensors) and able to make it last at least 1 month?

Comment: Such a question is not really answerable without an engineering specification of the sensor, or a plan to de-power it when not in use.  Overall, you're going to need to put a very large amount of effort into sleeping your system and avoiding any unintended leakage paths.

Comment: (1) Your moisture sensor is very popular among hobbyists. It works from 3V3 to 5V0. (2) There is a NE555 astable inside, should be taking not much current, especially with 3V3 power. (3) You might find more details from my answer to the following Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522956/capacitive-moisture-sensor-not-quite-working. Cheers.

Comment: (4) If your capatitive mode moisture sensor is using TTL NE555, working continuously in astable mode, then it might draw bigger current than you expect. (5) You might like consider other resistive resistor mode sensor which CMOS OPamp drawing very little current, comparing to NE555.